# How to define a function to take instance as argument in methods in class and call it from test file?

Tags: c++

I am making a header file with class definition

```
class Aclass{
private:
       int a;
       int b;
public:
       void getters/setters();
       void somefunction(Aclass& inst);
}
```

so this is what i try doing. But it does not work. I tried calling the function latter with instance as argument.

```
Aclass someinst;
Aclass::somefunction(someinst);
```

It gives out error as:

```
Cannot call member function 'void Aclass::somefunction(Aclass&)' without object
```

Comment: Make `somefunction` `static`.

Comment: wow magic! can you please explain me a bit on this.
and yes it is working now thank you so much :)

Comment: A `static` member function belongs to the scope of its class but doesn't require an instance of the class to be called. I suggest consulting a textbook for more details.

Comment: @user2678614 Though I'm not sure, a `static` function is **really** what you want.

Comment: I am also not sure with the use of static. I am an amateur in programming and trying to learn a bit. The course that I am taking has not talked about static functions yet so I am also a bit skeptical to its use. However, for now it is working well, so till there is better solution that i find, I will try this.

Comment: @user2678614 See my answer, hope it gives you some points ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have a 'non-static' member function of a class like `somefunction()`, you don't need to pass a class instance reference, to operate on the class member variables (passing of the `this` pointer is implicit for 'non-static' member functions):

```
class Aclass {
private:
   int a;
   int b;
public:

   void somefunction();
};
```

In a definition of the function you can directly access the class instances member variables:

```
void Aclass::somefunction()
{
   a = 5; // Sets the private member variable a
}
```

**Calling the member function works like follows:**

```
Aclass someinst;
someinst.somefunction(); // Using this syntax, the someinst class instance is implicitly
                         // passed to the somefunction() call
```

An exception to this is, if you really want to have **other** class instances as parameters, as commonly used for comparison operators, or copy operations:

```
class Aclass {
public:

    bool operator<(const Aclass& otherInst) const 
    {
        return (a < otherInst.a) && (b < otherInst.b);
    }

    Aclass& operator=(const Aclass& otherInst)
    {
        a = otherInst.a;
        b = otherInst.b;
        return *this;
    }
};
```